# Journey Builder Recurring schedule

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, schedule, recurring

I'm trying to set up journey builder as a daily recurring schedule basis.

The process would be;

1. Select Recurring (schedule)
2. Set up start date (ex: 2023/12/20)
3. Set up end date (Daily, every 1 day, end on date 2023/12/25)

If I proceed set up as above, and send an email,

- is the email sent until 2023/12/24 as a daily basis, and the journey finishes on 2023/12/25?
  Email sent 4 times (2023/12/20~2023/12/24)

Or,

- is the email sent until 2023/12/25 as a daily basis, and the journey finshes on 2023/12/25?
  Email sent 5 times (2023/12/20~2023/12/25)

Thank you

Comment: Please go through your previous questions and mark the answers as accepted. I can see that multiple of them have good quality and should be accepted to show the community they are indeed relevant and helpful

Comment: I wasn't aware of marking the answers. Thanks for your notice, I marked them as accepted. If possible, can you help me with the answers to my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, your first answer would be the correct one. The journey would evaluate daily until 12/25 (i.e. end on 12/25). It would run 5 times though...on 12/20, 12/21, 12/22, 12/23, 12/24.

If you're attempting to have the journey evaluate and run for a set number of occurrences (i.e. days), you could also use the "end after" option and set the number of occurrences accordingly. I hope this helps.